# Ping on bash script, ping if down then exit script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ping

I am making a bash script to configure some devices we use, but im trying to make a log in it, in other words.. when the script starts checks the date, time , user, and other values and then >  this values to a csv in a remote server.

I need the ping to check if the server its available, and if it doesnt, then quit program.

so i tried.

> ping -c 1 X.X.X.X >/dev/null || exit;

and it worked but i need to echo why it stopped, so i tried:

> ping -c 1 x.x.x.x >/dev/null || echo " The remote server is unavailable" ; exit;

Buen when i do this the program exits even if the ping went well..

In less words, im trying after "||" to have an echo and then exit the script, and im not sure how to do it. Everything else works like sharm, and if i remove the echo, the exit; option works fine..

Thanks in advance for your help.

Noobie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say:

```
ping -c 1 x.x.x.x >/dev/null || { echo " The remote server is unavailable" ; exit; }
```

`{ ... }` denotes [command grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) and the commands within it would be executed in a sequence.

`;` is a command separator.  So when you say:

```
ping -c 1 x.x.x.x >/dev/null || echo " The remote server is unavailable" ; exit;
```

`exit` is invoked regardless of the result of the previous command.

Comment: I just learned something.. im really noob on programing but im learning and with this help i think i will do it fast.. Thanks devnull for your help, really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you check `$?`. If it is **0** pig was successful.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks but the command grouping its more alike i was looking for. thanks! :)